# Is there any light weight Java Message Queue for Backend process communication?

Tags: java

I am developing a application , in which backend will be in java. In backend there are many processes. For communication I require message queue. I have searched for message queue in java , I got JMS. But as i know that is for Web applications and that will increase overhead in our project. so is there any basic light weight java message queue?

Answer (score 2):

JMS is a standard and not a concrete implementation. Investigating the offer on JMS implementations is your best route. `ActiveMQ` is a well-known implementation. It **is** industrial-strength, but it is not of necessity heavyweight. There may be other offerings as well.

Answer (score 1):

Any additional component will add some overhead, the question is how much. On production we use HornetQ, and when [properly configured](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html/perf-tuning.html) it can be [fast](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HornetQ-ThePerformanceLeaderInEnterpriseMessaging). Or [even faster](http://planet.jboss.org/post/8_2_million_messages_second_with_specjms)

There are also many alternatives, among those considered 'light':

- [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/)
- [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)

Comment: Thanks for information, I  will try it out, if it will be useful for me.